# Map unique values in 2 columns to integers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 2 categorical columns (col1, col2).

```py
  col1 col2
0    A   DE
1    A    B
2    B   BA
3    A    A
4    C    C
```

I want to map the unique string values to integers, for example (A:0, B:1, BA:2, C:3, DE:4)

```py
  col1 col2  ideal1  ideal2
0    A   DE       0       4
1    A    B       0       1
2    B   BA       1       2
3    A    A       0       0
4    C    C       3       3
```

I am have tried to use factorize or category, but I am **not getting the same unique value for both columns**, as can be seen from ROW C:

Here is my code:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ["A", "A", "B", "A" , "C"], 'col2': ["DE", "B", "BA", "A", "C"]}) 

#ideal map alphabetical: A:0, B:1, BA:2, C:3, DE:4

 #ideal result 
df["ideal1"] = [0, 0, 1,0, 3]
df["ideal2"] = [4,1,2,0,3]


 #trial #1 --> C value 2 & 3 : not matching
df["cat1"] = df['col1'].astype("category").cat.codes
df["cat2"] = df['col2'].astype("category").cat.codes

 #trial #2 --> C value 2 & 4 : not matching 
df["fac1"] = pd.factorize(df["col1"])[0]
df["fac2"] = pd.factorize(df["col2"])[0]


 
print (df)

OUT: 

  col1 col2  ideal1  ideal2  cat1  cat2  fac1  fac2
0    A   DE       0       4     0     4     0     0
1    A    B       0       1     0     1     0     1
2    B   BA       1       2     1     2     1     2
3    A    A       0       0     0     0     0     3
4    C    C       3       3     2     3     2     4
```

Comment: Try this; https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html

Comment: @JohnStud, I tried factorize, however since I have more unique values in col2, the factorize results for col1 & 2 don't line up - as can be seen by row 4 C Values for fac1 & fac 2 = 2, 4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the same categories across columns you need to reshape to a single dimension first. Then use `factorize` and restore the original shape.

Here is an example using `stack`/`unstack`:

```
x = df.stack()
x[:] = x.factorize()[0]
df2 = x.unstack()
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2
0    0    1
1    0    2
2    2    3
3    0    0
4    4    4
```

Joining to the original data:

```
x = df.stack()
x[:] = x.factorize()[0]
df2 = df.join(x.unstack().add_suffix('_cat'))
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2 col1_cat col2_cat
0    A   DE        0        1
1    A    B        0        2
2    B   BA        2        3
3    A    A        0        0
4    C    C        4        4
```

###### alphabetical order

If you really want alphabetical order, you could create you own custom mapping dictionary:

```
import numpy as np
cats = {k:v for v,k in enumerate(np.unique(df.values))}
df.replace(cats)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2
0     0     4
1     0     1
2     1     2
3     0     0
4     3     3
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked very fast even with a larger dataset!

Comment: @Leo I added an update for alphabetical order, might be slower though ;)

Comment: apologies for the wrong edit there

Comment: @sammywemmy the dictionary comprehension was intentional, this is needed to inverse keys and values ;) No worries, your edits are usually nice improvements!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a preference about which codes map to which integers, I would suggest using [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), which accepts a dictionary specifying how the mapping should be done.

Example:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ["A", "A", "B", "A" , "C"], 'col2': ["DE", "B", "BA", "A", "C"]}) 

mapping_dict = {'A':0, 'B':1, 'BA':2, 'C':3, 'DE':4}
df['ideal1'] = df['col1'].map(mapping_dict)
df['ideal2'] = df['col2'].map(mapping_dict)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2  ideal1  ideal2
0    A   DE       0       4
1    A    B       0       1
2    B   BA       1       2
3    A    A       0       0
4    C    C       3       3
```

The advantage of @mozway's solution is that you don't need to specify the mapping.

Comment: Thanks, In my original problem I have about 200 categories so won't be mapping from dictionary, but very useful answer.